# Creating new unique ImageViews and Animations

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview

I want to create new unique ImageViews which will be used in Animations. What I mean is that I want to create new ImageViews while there are other ImageViews (with the same type of Animation) running. The way it is now is that I create an ImageView, and then when I repeat the method, the ImageView created is cancelled and the new one starts. Also, each new ImageView should have a random y-coordinate (between 0 and 1920).

I don't really have any idea on how to achieve this in a way other than creating a  lot of ImageViews, but I'm sure there is a better option.

An example on what I mean is in the game CookieClicker (http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) where the cookies (that are to the left) are falling down when you press the big cookie.

```
Animation cowrunning;
ImageView cow;
cowrunning = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.cow_move);
cow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.runningcow);
cow.startAnimation(cowrunning);
```

This is how the code looks like now, however when I execute this a second time before the first animation has ended, the first animation is cancelled. I want to be able to create and run around 30 animations with the same image.

Comment: What you have tried upto now? and Where you have face problem?? Can you please explain that too???

Comment: Add the ImageView only when the current animation has ended.